# how to create scrollable list for gear vr in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I have created a scroll list using canvas screenspace camera mode which is not visible in gear VR, is there any other way to create scroll list like using canvas world space mode?

Comment: YES! [this](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/30/unity-4-6-new-ui-world-space-canvas/)  and [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/official-new-ui-system-coming-in-unity-4-6.248524/) will be good point to start.